# Can I spell queller a reduced-cost spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent casts Starfield of Nyx with Herald of the Pantheon in play. Herald reduces the cost of Starfield by 1 to 4.

I cast Spell Queller.

Can I quell the Starfield as it's CMC has been reduced to 4 or is it still 5?

Comment: Not a dupe, since this is while it's on the stack, well I suppose some of the answers partially cover it so it's a semi dupe.

Comment: Did you read the answer? Specifically the second paragraph and the quoted rule?

Comment: Yeah, it's not a dupe of the question but it is answered by the answers so I guess we can close as dupe :)

Comment: The specific example used is different, but this question could ask 'Do effects that reduce a spell's casting cost also reduce its converted mana cost?' with your example and it would be the exact same question.